# Google maps v3 zoom flickering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this problem where when i am zooming on my map with a groundoverlay it will flicker everytime it zooms and rearrange markers, the only problem with this is that my overlay gets reloaded everytime and resulting in white flickering and not showing the overlay in a sec or 2.

Link to my application: http://webgonic.dk/aarhusweather/

Is this just the way it is or is it possible to make the flickering stop ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why im getting downvotes, a comment on this would be nice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible, as this is the way google is loading it's images, this might have been a dumb question but it isnt answered anywhere on SO.